# Android Navigation - Define Argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I have some problems, when I define an argument in fragment, the letters in name Attribute of Argument display in red color but I see green tick in top XML file that means no problems found. My Android Studio is Giraffe version.

The message of this error is :
'firstName' is not a valid destination for tag 'argument'. I tried for other words but each time I have this error. I compiled and ran it on the emulator and everything looked good and it runs correctly.

[image: screenshot of 'firstName' is not a valid destination for tag 'argument']

I updated my Android Studio to Giraffe to solve repository problems of navigation and now I have this problem. It seems a problem with Android Studio.

build.gradle.kts (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        val nav_version = "2.6.0"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.0" apply false
}
```

build.gradle.kts (App)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    //id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.e12s02_navigationcomponent"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.e12s02_navigationcomponent"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    //Navigation Component
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0")
}
```

main_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.e12s02_navigationcomponent.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.e12s02_navigationcomponent.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_secondFragment_to_firstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/firstFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="firstName"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is a bug in Android Studio Giraffe. I download and install Android Studio Flamingo and everything works fine.

Other bug in Android Studio Giraffe is in MotionLayout that start and end Layout doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I honestly can't understand how it is possible that a bug of this magnitude hasn't come up before, or that there are no other references online than this stackoverflow question

Comment: yeah I have the same issue, in Flamingo it is ok, in Giraffe all the argument's names are in red!

Comment: Found an issue in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/293665984

Comment: Could this be why the FragmentDirections won't take the argument?

Comment: I have this problem too, but in android studio iguana canary 3 version.Is there any kind of solutions that would fix it ?

Comment: Really an annoying bug. Was expected to be fixed at Iguana Canary version 8 but they claim it's fixed at Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 7 with
Android Gradle Plugin 8.3.0-alpha07

Comment: It's still present in Hedgehog patch 1.

Comment: I get the same error message, but my code still works:

`Inspection info: This inspection highlights invalid destinations in the name attributes of the fragment and activity tags of navigation resource files.`

Answer (score 4):

To suppress this kind of error, you also can `suppress` it to prevent `git commit errors`. Add this line to `top of file`:

```
<!--suppress NavigationFile -->
```

like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress NavigationFile -->
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
```

Comment: thank you, i hated seeing 89 errors on my git commit everytime